# python writerow([variable]) instead of actual row

Tags: python, csv

```
f.writerow([field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6, field7, field8, field9, field10, field11, field12, field13, field14, field15, field16, field17, field18, field19, field20, field21, field22])
```

I want to replace that above with:

```
f.writerow([hrow])
```

the amount of fields can change depending on other things and I want to just append the fields to a variable if they're to be involved or not. When I print hrow I get exactly this:

```
field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6, field7, field8, field9, field10, field11, field12, field13, field14, field15, field16, field17, field18, field19, field20, field21, field22
```

But I guess it's not in the correct format because it prints it all into one cell in the first row and column, but each should be a header. I'm assuming you can't use a string variable in this case. But is there a way to do this?

EDIT: results after using f.writerow(hrow)

[image]

more info:

[image]

EDIT: Resolved.

changed the declaration to this

```
hrow = (args.sfdcfield1).split()
```

and appended the args that were valid to hrow.
then

```
f.writerow(hrow)
```

worked.

Thanks Daniel Roseman.
I'll work on optimizing the code once its working as I want. (its the long way around, but it helps me learn)

```
:)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit hard to follow, but I think you mean that you have a list of values in the `hrow` variable, and you want to write them all out as individual fields in the CSV row. In which case you just pass the list without wrapping it in another one:

```
f.writerow(hrow)
```

**Edit**

You should not be building up `hrow` by string concatenation. You should make it a list, and append each element to it.

```
hrow = []
if ...whatever...:
    hrow.append(value)
```

Note that even though we can't see the rest of the code, it looks *very* strange. It is unlikely that you need lots and lots of variables called things like `idxsfdcfield21`; more likely you need a list called `idxsfdc`, and again you append each element to it. And you could probably avoid hundreds of lines of code by simply looping over `args` in the first place.

Comment: I think the `*` is not appropriate, you just want `writerow(hrow)` (without the brackets that the questioner was using).

Comment: Yes you could be right, as I say the question was hard to understand. Updated.

Comment: Thanks. I understand why that would be the case and not using the [] now that you point it out. However, I got weird results using f.writerow(hrow). Instead of putting each arg into the sheet in a cell, it took the value of the variables and put each letter into a cell. so like field1 equates to IDNum my result is I D N u m all in their own header cells per letter. And so on for all the variables in the hrow variable

Comment: Can you please show what `hrow` is and where it is coming from - with actual code, not an image of the code.

Comment: You're probably right. I'm still learning python, this is my first python app. but basically. it pulls the args from a properties file. each field has a unique name.  the script takes text data and parses it and preps it for import to a new system that needs CSV. the sfdc header name is the final header name the new system expects. the extfield name is the one that it sees from the external data.  right now it accounts for 22 fields/headers/columns. but I want to be able to open it up to up to 40, but not NEED 40